# erase lines after drawing them in PyGTK- Cairo

Tags: drawing, pygtk, line, erase

I want to ask how can I erase a line witch I've drawn by using the pyGTK 
I used:cairo library

```
cr = widget.window.cairo_create()
cr.move_to(x, y)
cr.line_to(x1, y1)
cr.stroke()
```

I want to delete this line after  drawing it on screen

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete the line; it's erased anyway during the next expose event, so you just have to wait until the next expose event and then *not* draw it.